# How to make multiple line plot in ggplot2 (rstudio) from replicate data

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have some long data (one observation per row) of different treatments at different time points. I would like to make the plot shown below where each line represents a treatment over time. The line should be the mean. I have some experience with ggplot but my knowledge only allows me to only make this graph when there is only single observations for each treatment group at each time step (geom_line).

[image]

It is a graph with time on the x axis, y for the response value and then the treatments are each in a different colour (with 3  dots at each time for each treatment (n=3) and a line following the average of these three values).

Comment: Please provide an example of your data in order to better understand what needs to be done. Also you can provide a link to your image, and someone will edit your question to display the image.

Comment: Thank you, it is from a paper I was reading. Here is the image: https://imgur.com/h8Kfyfp

Comment: Please, add an example to clarify your question.

Comment: Uploaded your image (once edit is approved).  Please, can you share your dataset in the question as well?  Make sure you share in a format that can be replicated, such as typing `dput(your.data)` in the console and pasting the output in the body of your question (formatted as code, please).  Finally, you mentioned you were able to create a plot - can you share that too?  If not, at least share the code used to create it and we can help.

Answer (score 0):

There are two approaches you can use, depending on your data set.  In the absence of your data, I'll show you both using the `iris` dataset.  It's not the best example dataset for this, but... it works to demonstrate these methods.

First, the basic plot:

```
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, color=Species)) + theme_bw() +
  geom_line()
p
```

[image]

So there's the general way to generate the plot.  From your description of your dataset, it seems you have an `x`, `y`, and `treatment` column that should correspond to the code above as `iris$Sepal.Length`, `iris$Sepal.Width` and `iris$Species`, respectively.

#### Method 1: Overlay a Plot of Aggregate Data

The first method has more prep work upfront, but sometimes it's just straightforward to use.  The idea is that you create a separate dataframe holding your summary data and then plot that as a separate call to `geom_line()`.  The advantage of this method is that you have access directly to the summary data, and it is therefore relatively easy to access an individual data point among that dataset.  So, if you plan to do any further plotting or analysis of the summary data... this might be the way to go.

Create your summary dataset.  There are lots of methods to do this - here I'm using `dplyr` methods:

```
library(dplyr)

iris_summary <- iris %>%
  group_by(Sepal.Length) %>%
  summarize(mean_width=mean(Sepal.Width))
```

Then create the plot by adding another call to `geom_line()`, but specifying the `data=` field to correspond to the summary dataset, `iris_summary`.  In addition, you will need to reference the `y=` aesthetic, since it is now called `iris_summary$mean_width` instead of `iris_summary$Sepal.Width`:

```
p1 <- p +
  geom_line(
    data=iris_summary,
    aes(y=mean_width),
    color='black', size=1
  )
p1
```

[image]

#### Method 2: Use stat_summary()

The second method is very straightforward, but does not make it simple to access and do anything with the aggregated data.  If all you want to do is plot that summary data as a line, then this is definitely the simplest.

```
p2 <- p +
  stat_summary(
    geom='line', fun=mean, aes(group=1),
    size=1, color='black'
  )
p2
```

I'm not showing the plot, since the result is identical to that of `p1` using Method 1 above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply! It is not exactly what I mean, but I understand my question may be a bit confusing as I wasn't able to add the image of the graph. Here is the graph I want: https://imgur.com/h8Kfyfp , here every group has a separate line (preferably with the points still visible). 
I'm sure your solution will also come in useful in the future so thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: Okay, I see.  Then it seems that you would want to use `stat_summary()` (method 2 above) to draw the line *for each treatment group*.  You keep your basic plot structure, but leave out the `geom_line()`.  The key here is that you want to assess stats on each treatment group, so you use that for your `group=` aesthetic:  `ggplot(df, aes(x=, y=, color=treatment, group=treatment) + geom_point() + stat_summary(geom='line', fun=mean)`.  That should work, I believe.  If you want specific help, please share your dataset in the question by pasting the output of `dput(your.dataframe)`.